# My firebase authentication process is too slow?It takes about five minutes to completely create an user account and redirect! How to speed up?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

My firebase authentication process is too slow?It takes about five minutes to completely create an user account and redirect! How to speed up?

Sharing the authentication code below(Same of that from firebase documentation)

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pswd)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this@RegistrationActivity) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success")
            val user = auth.currentUser
            updateUI(user)
        } else {
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
            Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
            Toast.makeText(
                baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            updateUI(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Being new to this I wasn't aware what to do?tried some of youtube methods but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new user, firebase holds its data unless you logout. After creating a user and redirected to after page, just use the below code with a button click:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
```

If that was not work then its about your internet speed, emulator's internet speed or firebase server's speed. In firebase consol check project settings and see which region your app installed, example if you are in Europa and using Usa servers it will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using a mobile device instead of emulator.And the issue was resolved

Comment: This answer should be a comment instead as it does not include a detailed solution or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my location in firebase console to my current location worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).